# Dockerizing multiple instanced of a node app with different arguments

Tags: node.js, docker

I have written a node app with a basic layout like this:

```
config/
package.json
service.js
```

The config folder contains an arbitrary number of JSON config files. What I want to do is start one instance of *service.js* for each config file. I can do that with a bash script that looks something like this:

```
for config in `find config -name '*.json'`
do
    node service.js $config
done
```

Now I want to run all of this in docker. This is where my questions start.

- Should I run all node processes in one docker container using something like **pm2** and the bash script above? How do I keep my container running when starting multiple processes with **pm2**? Could something like **supervisor** work dynamically?

**or**

- Should I start one docker container for one node process possibly using forever/nodemon or something similar to keep it alive?

All of this needs to happen dynamically. When I add a new config file and merge that into my production branch I want my deployment to automatically start a process for this file (restart one or all containers).

Comment: Docker containers normally follow the one process per container approach.  I'd think hard about if you really need to break that or if you should reconsider your approach.

Comment: So I guess having one process parsing the config files and doing all the work would be more in line with that principal?

Comment: That, or have multiple linked docker containers.  Depends on workload and planned production architecture. Depending on what he configs do, it might be more appropriate to make a different image for each setting.  Hard to say without more info.